# fgetc() can't read float

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, fgetc

I got a big problem using fgetc() and i can't figure it out... I try to parse a text file, everything compile but at the execution I got an infinite loop xor a segfault (Code::blocks), my text file is like that: {"USD_EUR": "0.8631364", "EUR_USD": "1.3964719"} with 16 rates change. I try to put all my float in rate[16]...

```
void read(float change[4][4], char* myFile)
{

    FILE* file = NULL;
    file = fopen(myFile, "r+");
    int value,i;
    float rate[16];
    char* str = "";
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        do
        {
            value = fgetc(file);
            printf("%c \n",value);
            while(value > 48 && value < 57)
            {
                value = fgetc(file);
                strcat(str, value);
                //printf("%s \n", str);
            }
            rate[i] = atof(str);
            i++;
            str = "";
        }while(value != EOF);// 125 = }  
        change[0][1] = rate[5];
        change[0][2] = rate[0];
        change[0][3] = rate[15];
        change[1][0] = rate[6];
        change[1][1] = rate[14];
        change[1][2] = rate[7];
        change[1][3] = rate[10];
        change[2][0] = rate[8];
        change[2][1] = rate[2];
        change[2][2] = rate[12];
        change[2][3] = rate[4];
        change[3][0] = rate[3];
        change[3][1] = rate[13];
        change[3][2] = rate[11];
        change[3][3] = rate[9];
        fclose(file);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Unable to read the file!\n");
    }
}
```

I also try with EOF but i only have the char before numbers then that goes out of the loop ex: {"USD_EUR": "

Comment: How much do you understand C strings? You can't just `str = ""`.

Comment: and are you trying to call `strcat(char *, int)`?

Comment: in 'change', the position change[0][0] is being skipped.

Comment: the line: while(value > 48 && value < 57) causes the '.' to exit the loop.  This is definitely not what you want.  also, 48 is 0, and 57 is 9 and those input values cause the loop to exit rather than being put into the str[] array.

Comment: `while (value > 48 && value < 57)` will skip the decimal separator.

Comment: Yeah but i don't know how long is my string

I skipped it voluntary, always the same value

Comment: the line: char * str = ""; is incorrect, suggest something like: char str[30] = {'\0'};  the current code has str pointing to a string in the .const section of the executable, that contains a '\0' byte.  Note, the .const section cannot be written to.  So writing there can/will result in a seg fault event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you simply use `fscanf`.

E.g

```
FILE *file;
int i = 0, status;
float value;
float rate[16];

file = fopen(myFile, "r");
if(file == NULL){
    printf("Unable to read the file!\n");
    return ;
}
while((status=fscanf(file, "%f", &value))!=EOF){
    if(status==1){
        rate[i++] = value;
        if(i==16)//full
            break;
    } else {
        fgetc(file);//one character drop
    }
}
fclose(file);
```

Comment: suggest #define MAX_INPUTS (16)  and used that in the code, and used perror() rather than printf() as that would output the reason the fopen failed, other wise, excellent code

Comment: also It seems that this should use a `double` to think in terms of retention accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1:

```
char* str = "";
```

Declares `str` as a pointer to a static string. This creates a literal `""` in memory and points `str` to it, which isn't anything you can safely change. You want something like

```
char str[30] = "";
```

Problems 2 and 3:

```
strcat(str, value);
```

Attempts to to append to `str`, which isn't safe or right. Also, as guest notes, you are trying to `strcat(char *, int)`, which isn't the correct usage. `strcat(char *, char *)` is correct. Note - this *doesn't* mean that you should `strcat(str, (char *) &value);` - you need to understand how strings are implemented as `char` arrays in C, particularly with regard to zero termination.

Problem 4:

```
str = "";
```

See user3629249's comment above. Given a proper declaration,

```
str[0] = '\0';
```

Would be correct.

Problem 5:

Again, with credit to user3629249,

> in 'change', the position change[0][0] is being skipped.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solutions provided in the other answers, when faced with a messy line of input to read, it may be easier to use the **line-oriented** input functions provided by `libc` (e.g. `fgets` or `getline`). Reading the data one line at a time into a buffer, often (not always) allows greater flexibility in parsing the data with the other tools provided by `libc` (e.g. `strtok`, `strsep`, etc..)

With other data, **character-oriented** input is a better choice. In your case, the lines were interlaced with numerous `'"'`, `':'`, `' '` and `','`'s. This made it difficult to construct a `fscanf` format string to read both exchange rates in a single call or use any of the string parsing tools like `strtok`. So this was truly a tough call. I agree, BluePixyes' solution for parsing a single `float` in a `fscanf` call is a good solution. The **line-oriented** alternative is to read a line at a time, and then using `strtof` to convert the float values found in the line. The only advantage that `strtof` provides is error checking on the conversion that allows you to verify a good float conversion. This is one approach for a **line-oriented** solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main () {

    FILE* file = NULL;              /* aways initialize variables   */
    float rate[16] = {0.0};         /* market rates 1st & 2nd       */
    char myFile[50] = {0};          /* input filename               */
    char line[128] = {0};           /* input line buffer            */
    char *p = NULL;                 /* pointer to parse line        */
    char *ep = NULL;                /* pointer to parse line        */
    size_t idx = 0;                 /* index for rate array values  */
    size_t it = 0;                  /* general index iterator       */

    /* prompt for filename  */
    printf ("\n Please enter filename to read rates from: ");
    scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", myFile);

    /* open & validate file */
    file = fopen (myFile, "r");
    if (!file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: Unable to read the file!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* using line-oriented input to read line, then parse */
    while (fgets (line, 127, file) != NULL)
    {
        if (idx == 16) {
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: array full.\n");
            break;
        }

        p = line;                           /* parse line for floats    */
        while (*p) {                        /* find first digit or end  */
            while (*p && (*p < 48 || *p > 57) ) p++;
            if (!*p) break;                 /* validate not null        */
            rate[idx++] = strtof (p, &ep);  /* get float, set end-ptr   */
            if (errno != 0 || p == ep)      /* validate conversion      */
                fprintf (stderr, "discarding: rate[%zd] invalid read\n", --idx);
            p = ep;                         /* set ptr to end-ptr       */
        }
    }

    fclose (file);

    printf ("\n The exchange rates read from file:\n\n");
    for (it = 0; it < idx; it++)
        printf ("  rate[%2zd]  =  %9.7f\n", it, rate[it]);

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**sample input:**

```
$ cat dat/rates.txt
"USD_EUR": "0.8631364", "EUR_USD": "1.3964719"
"USD_AGT": "0.9175622", "EUR_USD": "1.0975372"
"USD_BRZ": "0.8318743", "EUR_USD": "1.1713074"
"USD_COL": "0.9573478", "EUR_USD": "1.0537964"
"USD_GIA": "0.7904234", "EUR_USD": "1.5393454"
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/read_xchgrates

 Please enter filename to read rates from: dat/rates.txt

 The exchange rates read from file:

  rate[ 0]  =  0.8631364
  rate[ 1]  =  1.3964719
  rate[ 2]  =  0.9175622
  rate[ 3]  =  1.0975372
  rate[ 4]  =  0.8318743
  rate[ 5]  =  1.1713074
  rate[ 6]  =  0.9573478
  rate[ 7]  =  1.0537964
  rate[ 8]  =  0.7904234
  rate[ 9]  =  1.5393454
```

**Note:** check your `strtof` man page for any additional `#define`'s your compiler may require.

Answer (score 0):

the code has the following sequence:

fgetc results in 'U',

that is not a value inside the range 0...9 exclusive, 
so drops through to try and convert str to rate[i]

(where 'i' has not been initialized to a known value)

Since no digits have been saved where str points, 
some unknown offset from rate[] gets set to 0 
(this is undefined behaviour)

then the unknown value 'i' gets incremented
 and the following line: str = "" is executed

which has no effect on string 
(unless each literal is at a different location in the .const section)

and the outer loop is repeated.

Eventually, a char in the range 1...8 is input

Then, in the inner loop, that first digit is SKIPPED
and another char is read.

from your example that next char is a '.'
Which could cause the inner loop to be exited

However,
the line: strcat(str, value);
should cause  a seg fault event 
due to trying to write to the .const section of the executable